# load pictures from url into internal storage

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My goal is to download multiple images from given url's and save them into interal storage.

```
private void downloadImages(List<String> filename,JSONObject c) throws  Exception{
    String fileName = c.getString("name") + ".json";
    String data = "";
    File images = getDir("Images", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File dir = new File(images,fileName);
    System.out.println(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    List<Bitmap> pictures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String s : filename){

    }
}
```

The `List<String> filename` contain all the url's from the images.
So what i think i have to do is, to download the image for each url in `filename`
The structure is like this :

```
Images
------fileName
--------------Image1
--------------Image2
------fileName2
--------------Image1
--------------Image2
```

I would like to use this :

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://example.com/file.png", new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(/* Context */ this) {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
        // Do something with the file `response`
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the method you laid out not work as expected? Have you tried it?

Comment: My question is, what i have to do in the foreach to save the downloaded image in the structure i want.Which means -> create a subfolder with the name of the JSONObject and store there each image.

Answer (score 3):

Try this awesome lib provided by facebook [**Fresco**](http://frescolib.org/) powerful image caching and downloading.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following link: http://denniskubes.com/2012/11/16/android-image-downloading-and-caching/

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to see the images or use the images? if you just want to use the images then reinventing the wheel is no the way to go try using a library instead of implementing your own thing it will save you alot of stress and time try either [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) all that stuff is done for you.

Comment: I will need them later on

Comment: these images are cached on local storage just folow the documentation